# Nginx to host app in different location

Tags: php, nginx

I'm trying to serve [CachetHQ](https://cachethq.io/) in nginx + php-fpm in a specific location. The docs gives this as example that serves in `status.example.com` (which works):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name status.example.com;

    root /var/www/Cachet/public;
    index index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
         include fastcgi_params;
         fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
         fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
         fastcgi_index index.php;
         fastcgi_keep_conn on;
    }
}
```

However, instead of serving in `status.example.com`, I would like to serve in `example.com/status`.

I was expecting that this would work, but from error.log I see it's trying `/etc/nginx/htmlindex.php`, but it should be `/mnt/data/site/www-cachet/public/index.php`:

```
location /status/ {
    index index.php;
    root /mnt/data/site/www-cachet/public;

    try_files $uri index.php$is_args$args;

    location ~ ^/status/.+\.php$ {
        root /mnt/data/site/www-cachet/public;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/tmp/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_keep_conn on;
    }
}
```

Comment: The priority isn't right. It is firstly match `location /`

Comment: @ZYWJ well `location /` shouldn't be a problem since I wan't it to be in `/status`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After so many hours trying a lot of combinations, the way I got it working was:

```
location ^~  /status {
    alias /mnt/data/site/www-cachet/public;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @status;

    location = /status/ {
        rewrite /status/$ /status/index.php;
    }

    location ~ ^/status/(.+\.php)$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/tmp/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /mnt/data/site/www-cachet/public/$1;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}

location @status {
    rewrite /status/(.*)$ /status/index.php?/$1 last;
}
```

The most important thing was `fastcgi_param`, I had to set it to an absolute path instead of `$document_root$fastcgi_script_name` or something like it. I'm not sure if it's a good pratice, but adding `alias` to the block just doesn't work, and neither nginx or FastCGI show us the path of the file they're trying to read.

Nevertheless I couldn't get CachetHQ to work well. Problem is that all paths in source code are absolute, so they won't point to the subdirectory which our files are hosted. The solution was do something that I was reluctant since beginning: host it in a subdomain.

Answer (score 2):

Your `try_files` is not correct.
You can do it like this:

```
index index.php;
root /mnt/data/site/www-cachet/public;

location / {
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 last;
        break;
    }
}  

location ~ ^/status/.+\.php$ {
    root /mnt/data/site/www-cachet/public;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass   unix:/tmp/php-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_keep_conn on;
}
```

Comment: Nginx config test fails, saying that `location "/" is outside location "/status"`. I've modified to get rid of the errors. Then, log showed me that nginx send the script to FastCGI, but the HTTP response is "File not found". In error.log, the message is "Primary script unknown". Is there any way we see which path it is trying to access?

Answer (score 2):

Let me start with the original configuration that you claim works, and try to modify it for your requirements, results below:

```
location ^~ /status {
    alias /var/www/Cachet/public;
    index index.php;

    location = /status {
        return 302 /status/;
    }
    location / {
        try_files $uri /status/index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
         include fastcgi_params;
         fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
         rewrite ^/status/(.*) /$1;
         rewrite ^(.*)/ $1/index.php; # who knows what fastcgi_index is for?
         fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$uri;
         fastcgi_keep_conn on;
    }
}
```

Basically, you want to use [`alias`](http://nginx.org/r/alias) instead of `root` here, and probably also have an absolute path in the final `try_files` as well.  I don't think adding extra prefixes within nested locations is needed, but you might want to make sure that the root location is a final match with the `^~` modifier.

The main trick, I guess, is that even with the `alias` directive things aren't as dandy as with a proper `root`, so, you have to make sure that the `SCRIPT_FILENAME` is set correctly.  This part doesn't seem to be documented very clearly, and I'm too lazy to test out whether [`$fastcgi_script_name`](http://nginx.org/r/$fastcgi_script_name) [ngx variable](http://ngx.su/src/http/modules/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.c#ngx_http_fastcgi_script_name_variable) and [`fastcgi_index`](http://nginx.org/r/fastcgi_index) directive play nice with `alias` -- instead of trying to determine how those work (or not), we simply do a couple of `rewrite` rules as applicable, and construct `SCRIPT_FILENAME` based on the results of our rewrite rules instead. :-)

However, with that said, I'd think the second rewrite rule (as well as the `fastcgi_index` it replaces) might as well be a no-op, because how were we supposed to end up in a `\.php$` `location` if `$uri` didn't end in `.php` already?
(Likewise, you're free to try to remove the first rewrite rule, too, and replace `$uri` in `SCRIPT_FILENAME` with `$fastcgi_script_name`, and see if things still work, but the internet [from 2009](https://serverfault.com/questions/15031/can-nginx-handle-php-or-similar-fcgi-requests-inside-of-an-alias) may indicate that they didn't.)

Comment: Nginx config test says that `location "/" is outside location "/status"`. I'm using nginx/1.8.0. I modified `location /` to `location /status/` and I get 404, in error.log I see it's trying to access /etc/nginx/htmlindex.php.

Comment: @rodorgas, how exactly are you getting such 404 error?  I've never seen anyone having errors pointing out to `/etc/nginx/htmlindex.php`, there must be something else very weird about your configuration file or the way you copy-paste my example.  As for `/` outside `/status`, sure, just change it to `/status`, and it should be fine.

Comment: `curl http://site/status/` (curl so the response is not cached), /status/setup, and stuff, they all try the same weird location. I searched through ALL files in `/etc/nginx/`, where conf.d files and others are placed, and none of them have the `/etc/nginx/html` path. I doubled checked my copy-paste too, it's working as expected. Something strange is happening, and it could only be fixed by setting an absolute path instead of the (buggy?) variables.

Comment: @rodorgas, so, if you explicitly change `$document_root` with what the `alias` above is set to, in my example, then it works, right?